# Solving Augmented Matrix

Tags: matrices

Determine the values of $\lambda$ so that the following homogeneous linear system has only has the trivial solution:

$$\lambda x + y + z = 0$$

$$x + \lambda y + z = 0$$

$$x+ y + \lambda z = 0$$

I know that the trivial solution is $x=0,y=0,z=0$ (no non-trivial solution)

So how do I go about doing the matrix? So do I have it as a ref only or a rref? thanks

Trivial solution only has $0$, the nontrivial solution is non zero...

Comment: Do you know that fact that $Det(A)=0 \iff$ there is a non nontrivial solution?

Answer (score 2):

Let see when the determinant of the matrix is zero, if so that mean that the matrix is not invertible therefore there is a nontrivial solution.

$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda& 1&1\\
1&\lambda&1\\
1&1&\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$ Adding rows 2 and 3 to row 1 $\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+2& \lambda+2&\lambda+2\\
1&\lambda&1\\
1&1&\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$ taking out $\lambda+2$ 

$\lambda+2\begin{vmatrix}
1& 1&1\\
1&\lambda&1\\
1&1&\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$  subtracting row 1 from row 2 and row 3:   $\lambda+2\begin{vmatrix}
1& 1&1\\
0&\lambda-1&0\\
0&0&\lambda-1
\end{vmatrix}$ laplace expansion by column 1 $(\lambda+2)*1*$
$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda-1&0\\
0&\lambda-1
\end{vmatrix}=(\lambda+2)(\lambda-1)^2$

The matrix has only has the trivial solution if $\lambda\neq -2,1$

Comment: Nice! Using the explicit formula for a 3×3 determinant gives the polynomial faster, but then you'd have to factor it. Even quicker, though, is to subtract column 1 in your second matrix from each of columns 2 and 3, which leaves a lower triangular matrix, whose determinant is the product of the diagonal entries.

Comment: (Something typographic seems to have gone wrong with your formula after "expansion by column 1", tough).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You know the solution space includes the trivial solution.
If the system were unique it had only that solution.
How can you determine the uniqueness of the system?

$\lambda = 0:$
$$
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
0 &  1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 &  1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
= 2
$$

$\lambda \ne 0:$
$$
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \lambda & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\frac{1}{\lambda^2}
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
\lambda & \lambda^2 & \lambda \\
\lambda & \lambda & \lambda^2
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\frac{1}{\lambda}
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \lambda^2 & \lambda \\
1 & \lambda & \lambda^2
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\frac{1}{\lambda}
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \lambda^2 - 1 & \lambda - 1 \\
0 & \lambda - 1 & \lambda^2 - 1
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\frac{(\lambda - 1)^2}{\lambda}
\left\lvert
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \lambda + 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & \lambda + 1
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\frac{(\lambda - 1)^2}{\lambda}
((\lambda + 1)^2 - 1)
=
\frac{(\lambda - 1)^2}{\lambda}
(\lambda^2 + 2 \lambda)
=
(\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda + 2)
$$
This determinant vanishes for $\lambda \in \{-2, 1 \}$. If $\lambda$ is choosen differently the determinant does not vanish and the system is unique.